# Difference between "!= true" and "= false"

Tags: java, boolean

I've faced a situation where "!= true" gave me a different output than "= false". I thought that if something isn't true it'd be false automatically. Can anyone please explain me how it works? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us the **code** required to reproduce the situation you have encountered?

Comment: Using `==` and `!=` is redundant for booleans. You should use `if(booleanVariable)` and `if(!booleanVariable)` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've never understood why people feel compelled to use comparison operators to make Boolean expressions out of Boolean expressions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It gives different output because you confused with **Comparison vs Assignment**

`!=` will compares the value with RHS  and `=false` do an assignment to LHS. If you wish to check for equality use the `==` operator instead.

And I don't think it won't make much difference when you compare in difference styles since both do the same job unless you have some weird line of code.

Answer (score 1):

`==` is comparison operator, `=` is assignment operator
`!=` is **not equal to**, and `==` is **equal to**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers,

> if something isn't true it'd be false automatically

is also wrong.

`(Boolean) null != true` is true, but `(Boolean) null == false` is of course false.

Answer (score 0):

`!= true` is used a comparator. It compare the LHS to true. However `= false` is an assignment. An equivalent of `!= true` will be `== false`. `==` is also a comparator operator that checks for equality while `!=` checks for inequality.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about writing or checking the value...

look this example...

```
boolean flag = true; a boolean variable is defined and assig to true

if (flag!=true) { //you should do instead    if(!flag)
    //this is checking the content of the flag variable
}
if (flag=true) { //you should do instad    if(flag)
        //this is writing the content of the flag assigning it to true
}
```

Comment: Your second conditional is actually an assignment.

Comment: @takendarkk thanks for the point, I know I did that intentionally because it looks like the OP is assigning instead of checking the boolean val

Answer (score 0):

In a boolean statement, if you use **!= true**, if the boolean is null, the operator will allow it to run whatever it is comparing.  If you use **== false**, it will only run if the boolean is currently set to false.

Answer (score 0):

First is comparison, in later case you are assigning